# Use a list to check an array index

Tags: python, arrays, list

In python, I am generating lists to represent states (for example a state could be `[1,3,2,2,5]`).

The value of each element can range from 1 to some specific number. 
Based on certain rules, these states can evolve in particular ways. I am not interested in states I have already encountered.

Right now my code just checks whether a list is in a list of lists and if it isn't, it appends it. But this list is getting very large and using a lot of resources to check against.

I would like to

- create a multidimensional array of zeros,
- check a particular location in that array, and if that location is 0 set it to 1.

If I take the state stored as a list or as an array, adjust it by 1
to correspond to index values, and try to pass that value as an index
for the zeros array, it doesn't just change the one element.

I think this is because the list is in brackets, where index() wants an
argument of just integers separated by commas.

Is there a way to pass a list or array of integers to check an index of an array that won't add complication to my code? Or even just some more efficient way to
   store and check the states I have already generated?

Comment: If your states are lists, you can turn them into tuples and store them in a set or dictionary. This will allow for `O(1)` checking, rather than the `O(n)` checking that you seem to be doing now.

Answer (score 1):

You should maintain the states you have already encountered in a `set`. This ensures that a contains check (`state in visited`) is O(1), and not O(N). Since `lists` are not hashable, you would have to convert them to `tuples`, or use tuples in the first place:

```
visited = set()
states = [[1,3,2,2,5], [...], ...]

for state in states:
    tpl = tuple(state)
    if tpl not in visited:  # instant check no matter the size of visted
        # process state
        visited.add(tpl)
```

Your idea of creating this 5-dimensional list and passing the state values as indexes is valid, but would create a large (`n^5` n: number of values for each slot) and presumably sparse and therefore waisteful matrix. 
BTW, You access a slot in such a matrix via `m[1][3][2][2][5]`, not `m.index([1,3,2,2,5])`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may define a class of your state and use define its **hash function**. In this way, the running time of a lookup reduce to `O(1)` and the space required reduce to `O(N)`, where `N` is the **number of states** instead of **number of state * state size**

A sample class of the state:

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self, state_array):
        self.state_array = state_array
    def getHash(self):
        return hash(self.state_array)    # using python default hash function here, you can totally design your own.
```

When storing current state:

```
# current_state is the state you currently have
all_states = {}
if current_state.getHash() not in all_state:
    all_states[current_state.getHash()] = 1
else:
    # Do something else
```

Note that in python, `element in dict`  takes `O(1)` because a `dict` in python is actually a hashmap.

Comment: The problem with storing hashes of states is that you might get collisions, especially if the number of states is large. Python's `set` implementation handles collisions automatically. Also -- if you are computing hashes then storing the hashes in a set then you are in effect hashing each state twice, once to get the hash and once to store the hash. The only valid use-case for this approach is if the state vectors themselves are large (and not just numerous), though in that case you would need to make sure that the probability of collisions is negligible. A good idea for this case, so +1.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that `set` handles collisions automatically